# gganimate lots of stacked geom_col producing white spaces in the animation

Tags: r, gganimate

I am building an animation of stacked bar charts (calling `geom_col`). I have 100 columns. When I generate the animation I get a lot of white space in what should be filled columns.

See the gif below:

[image]

That gif is based on about 100k rows of data, so I can't post it all here. Notably, I can't reproduce this in a simpler example:

```
library('tidyverse')
library('gganimate')

data.frame(time = rep(1:50, 200)) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(type = rep(c(rep('A', 100), rep('B', 100)), 50), 
         class = rep((1:100), 100), 
         value = runif(10000, 0, 1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = value, fill = type)) +
  geom_col() +
  transition_time(time)
```

Works fine (ignoring the structure in the above data, but i don't get the white spaces):

[image]

I tried adding `ease_aes()`, `enter_fade()`, `exit_fade()`, but none of that worked. Anyone have thoughts on what is causing this?

---UPDATE---

Following the comments I tried filtering the data down to see what was going on. Reducing to just two countries and 5 years of data, the problem appears to be that chunks of data are moving between percentiles. When what I want is for them to just grow and shrink within each percentile. You can see it in the gif below:

[image]

The data that produced this is here:

```
structure(list(country = c("US", "DE", "US", "US", "US", "DE", 
"US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "DE", "US", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "US", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", 
"US", "DE", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", 
"DE", "US", "US", "DE", "US", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", 
"US", "DE", "DE", "US", "DE", "DE", "US", "US", "DE", "US", "US", 
"DE", "US", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", 
"DE", "US", "DE", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "US", "US", "DE", "US", 
"DE", "US", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", "DE", "US", 
"DE", "US", "US", "DE", "US", "US", "DE", "US", "US", "DE", "US", 
"DE", "US", "DE", "US", "DE"), glob.perc = c(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 
8, 9, 9, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9), 
    avg.income.country = c(437288.3, 95483.3754884956, 140784.030084749, 
    140733.5, 92860.7570361667, 27041.1685330627, 82474.4007614941, 
    22845.1776491941, 75584.1480877374, 20954.7760014288, 70400.3370710519, 
    19852.2326809271, 54038.6152996391, 15598.3057384556, 15170.9872445152, 
    62785.1002246113, 18201.6743099168, 39606.7790727414, 39051.1193095399, 
    450574.9, 89747.1381942579, 143040.424101143, 144413.3, 95281.4131057479, 
    26564.8030858664, 84645.1806598295, 22453.3134663253, 99495.4, 
    58448.7245539485, 16815.8081430027, 15925.4607078112, 67342.4870614877, 
    18775.7716260376, 52078.6261482834, 14908.4732454128, 14586.6597398625, 
    60740.8587598986, 17551.4029073371, 449672.7, 85860.9513060095, 
    138573.062299181, 107999.713224424, 26551.7207203881, 118606.7, 
    81673.5478130351, 22256.5124499113, 74664.7815210055, 20289.8692320157, 
    69424.4509484861, 19130.6427260963, 53441.6796042233, 15011.8413898757, 
    14554.8379632521, 62031.6543795656, 17372.7239256402, 17038.0153770701, 
    59253.6721580242, 478696.8, 87965.3040019279, 141489.41469306, 
    110750.734809188, 28139.4736007857, 121395.4, 84564.2106500617, 
    23136.9326230234, 77452.4071740221, 20809.5254887263, 72187.8010950261, 
    19423.2184457137, 67965.6133547784, 18489.4603327709, 64700.6833849069, 
    17811.5804850837, 50612.3590346861, 14165.4003733601, 13829.472811758, 
    542123.2, 89948.9091254987, 158338.248242006, 156908.9, 104475.681782063, 
    29031.666816329, 92305.5514014955, 23750.4970524401, 107775.8, 
    78090.1791649968, 21282.8059573008, 73283.2631907787, 19808.7465702618, 
    69304.0213872794, 18813.7418777938, 65958.7178466761, 18090.1791160505, 
    559720.3, 92129.3365959901, 159846.146463587, 123870.105638014, 
    30030.7222753586, 135301.9, 94785.176213572, 24358.2621716462, 
    110644.4, 80286.8697338142, 21690.4391200441, 75280.156096728, 
    20090.0002975319, 71136.641950609, 19006.2143886443, 67594.6662796918, 
    18216.0069568407), region = c("Americas", "Europe", "Americas", 
    "Americas", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", 
    "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Europe", 
    "Americas", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", 
    "Americas", "Americas", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", 
    "Europe", "Americas", "Americas", "Europe", "Europe", "Americas", 
    "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", 
    "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", 
    "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", 
    "Americas", "Europe", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Europe", 
    "Americas", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Americas", 
    "Europe", "Americas", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", 
    "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", 
    "Americas", "Europe", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", 
    "Americas", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", 
    "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", 
    "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Americas", 
    "Europe", "Americas", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Americas", 
    "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", "Europe", "Americas", 
    "Europe"), year = c(1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
    1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
    1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
    1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
    1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 
    1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 
    1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
    1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
    1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1984L, 1984L, 
    1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
    1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
    1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
    1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L)), row.names = c(NA, -110L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code for the animation is as follows:

```
df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = glob.perc, y = avg.income.country/1000, fill = region)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'stack') +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(subtitle = "Year: {frame_time}", 
       x = element_blank(), 
       y = element_blank(), 
       fill = 'Region') +
  transition_time(year)
```

My sense is this is not an issue of missing data - at each year the visualization is complete without whitespace. i think its an issue of how the `geom_col()` transitions.

Comment: Two possibilities that come to mind are 1) Regions that are NA or besides what you've specified in your code that you haven't included. 2) some time / x / category combinations aren't in the data, but should be added with `complete()`

Comment: It will be hard to solve this without a reproducible example. Presumably you are only using a few columns in your code, and presumably you will have the same issue if you filter your x-axis variable to some subset, say 0-5. Try filtering the data mercilessly and see where / if the problem goes away. I'm confident there is a much smaller subset of your data that will have the same issue. You might also summarize the data, eg with `%>% dplyr::count(x_var, Region, wt = y_var, name = "y_var")` so that it isn't 100k rows but perhaps a few dozen for some subset of data.

Comment: @JonSpring Thanks for this. I tried filtering down and the problem seems to be with the animation, not with the structure of the data. Added details to the question.

Comment: Your data doesn't seem totally summarized, in that some year/country/glob.perc combinations have multiple income values (eg 1980|DE|7 or 9), most have 1, and some are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gganimate is running into trouble with your data set since some year/country/glob.perc values have multiple observations and some have zero. It's assuming (incorrectly) that some of the values you are tracking are moving between glob.perc categories year to year. One way to solve this would be to make there be one and only one value for each year/country/glob.perc combination. Here, I put the avg.income.country at zero for the missing ones. There's probably a smarter way to do this, perhaps with imputed values based on neighboring ones or a regression model.

```
df %>%  
  group_by(year, region, country, glob.perc) %>%
  summarize(avg.income.country = mean(avg.income.country), n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(year, nesting(country, region), glob.perc, fill = list(avg.income.country = 0)) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = glob.perc, y = avg.income.country/1000, fill = region)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'stack', color = "black", alpha = 0.7) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(subtitle = "Year: {frame_time}", 
       x = element_blank(), 
       y = element_blank(), 
       fill = 'Region') +
  transition_time(year)
```

[image]

---

Here's a look the number of observations in the original data. Note that some are doubled up and some are missing. This creates an ambiguity for gganimate, since it's unclear whether the unit you're tracking has disappeared (it has) or whether it has moved to another glob.perc category (what gganimate assumed).

```
df %>%  
  count(year, region, country, glob.perc) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, glob.perc, fill = n)) +
  geom_tile() +
  facet_wrap(~country)
```

[image]

Plotting these as lines, we can see that something is a little fishy in the underlying data. You might take another look there and see if your glob.perc code is working the way you intend. If the categories mean what they sound like, I would have assumed the lines would not cross.

```
df %>%  
  filter(country == "DE", glob.perc >= 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, avg.income.country, color = as.character(glob.perc), group = glob.perc)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~country)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't quite work, but you were correct to point out that i needed unique observations. If you want to put this in an answer i'll give you the reputation. I tried to post the answer below.

Comment: This is an answer, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks Jon, what i needed to do was get them to single values, to remove the ambiguity. I did that via `df %>% group_by(group_by(glob.perc, year, region) %>%
  summarize(avg.income.country = sum(avg.income.country)) %>% [ggplot call]`. it doesn't work with the filtered data i used here as there are so few observations that the values aren't unique and the ambiguity for gganimate remains.

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing are the single states at each time steps. But there is no much change in `value` from one step to the other which leads to the flickering. I believe what you want to see  is something like below.

For this I have grouped the data `group_by` and added a column `sum` as the cumulated value-data.

The `filter` is there to limit rendering times.

```
library('tidyverse')
library('gganimate')

ddf_anim <- data.frame(time = rep(1:50, 200)) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(type = rep(c(rep('A', 100), rep('B', 100)), 50), 
         class = rep((1:100), 100), 
         value = runif(10000, 0, 1)) %>%
  filter(time <10) %>% 
  group_by(class, type) %>% 
  mutate(sum = cumsum(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = sum, fill = type)) +
  geom_col() +
  transition_time(time)


ddf_anim
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate this, but don't think its what i am looking for. My point in posting this gif above, was that it did not produce the whitespace the way my actual case did. I have updated the question which i think shows the problem with the animation.